# Converting arrays nested in array into object using forEch (does not work somehow?)

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, foreach

I am having trouble with something i thought it will be simple.

I have an array of nested arrays with strings.

```
const cities = [['Vienna'],['Berlin'],['London'],['Oslo'],['New York']]
```

I must convert these nested arrays into objects. I think forEach method should suit perfectly along with Object.assign.

I written something like these:

```
function convert(element) {
    Object.assign({}, element)
  }
  const Test = cities.forEach(convert)
```

But then i am getting from `console.log(Test)` undefinded. Why so ? I am iterating through the whole array and each of her arrays should be assign as object. Whats missing ?

Comment: Object should contain `key: value` pair

Comment: `forEach` always returns `undefined`. You might be looking for `.map()` but your `convert` does not return anything, either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Object should contain key: value pair*

If you want to convert each string element into an object element. Then you can do something like this **:**

```js
const cities = [['Vienna'],['Berlin'],['London'],['Oslo'],['New York']]

const res = cities.map((item) => {
    return {
    city: item[0]
  }
});

console.log(res);
```

Comment: is the flat necessary. map and item[0]?

Comment: You are right. Sorry i missed that. Thanks for pointing that out. I updated the answer.

Comment: Thanks, thats explain a lot. And its even simpler and straight forward.